# PHP SQL Get the sum of 2 first records from table

Tags: php, sql

How can I get the sum of the daily_rate_price field but only from the first two rows? Table name is daily_rates

| daily_rate_id | daily_rate_date | daily_rate_price | daily_rate_reservation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1480 | 2021-11-18 | 280.00 | 320 |
| 1481 | 2021-11-19 | 280.00 | 320 |
| 1482 | 2021-11-20 | 280.00 | 320 |

I tried something like this, but it apparently does not work:

```
$accomTotal=" SELECT SUM(daily_rate_price) AS accomTotal FROM daily_rates   
WHERE daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId  LIMIT 2 ;";
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do the LIMIT part in a derived table. SUM() its result.

Comment: BTW, _rows_, not records.

Comment: tag your database

Comment: @jarlh xammp but I need to perform the query in my php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use a subquery:

```
select sum(daily_rate_price) AS accomTotal 
from ( 
  select daily_rate_price from daily_rates 
  where daily_rate_reservation=$reservationId  
  order by daily_rate_date asc limit 2 
) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)